# Error while trying to assign user to app

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

As the title indicates, I'm getting an error while trying to assign a user to an AAD application.
Here is the request and the error I'm getting

[image]

[image]

[image]

Obviously it's related to the version of the API but I can't get it to work even with changing the api-version parameter.

**Update** :
When I modify the request url to https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/..., I get the following error : `Unsupported segment type. ODataQuery: users/{userid}/appRoleAssignments`

**Update 2** :
Even with beta version, this seems not to be working :

**Update 3** : 
Is this still available in beta version of MS Graph? otherwise is there any alternatives (other than powershell and graph api) to achieve what I want programatically
    https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/{userId}/appRoleAssignments/{appRoleId}

Still getting `Unsupported segment type` error

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? The URL's you're using are not Microsoft Graph API calls.

Comment: I'm trying to programatically assign users to an aad app

Comment: @MarcLaFleur how aren't they Microsoft Graph API calls?

Comment: I manage to get user details with the same url (https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/{tenantid}/users/{userid}/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Marc's answer is correct - with a couple of caveats:
 1. This is only available in /beta, and not recommended for production.
 2. There's a bug that is preventing this from working.

To do this in production, the only current option for you is to use Azure AD Graph API.  You'll see that our docs recommend the use of Microsoft Graph everywhere, but there are a few places where there are some gaps with Azure AD Graph.

More info on what's supported in Microsoft Graph vs Azure AD Graph look at this topic https://dev.office.com/blogs/microsoft-graph-or-azure-ad-graph

The API calls are the same as Marc has above, but with a different root URL and versioning scheme. So it looks something like this:

`POST https://graph.windows.net/{tenantId}/users/{userId}/appRoleAssignments?api-version=1.6
{ 
  "id": "31952ade-a03c-414c-8340-2f11e9099106",
  "principalId":  "84b80893-8749-40a3-97b7-68513b600544",
  "principalType": "User",
  "resourceId":  "29c7ed43-a9a1-4b31-8a64-fc90c3ca4e73" 
}`

See either this [older blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/aadgraphteam/2014/12/12/announcing-the-new-version-of-graph-api-api-version1-5/) or the [AAD Graph reference docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/api/entity-and-complex-type-reference#approleassignment-entity)

Hope this helps,

Answer (score 2):

The URL you're using here isn't a valid Microsoft Graph call.

AS a REST API, each segment of the URL is effectively an API namespace or method (depending if it's the final URI segment). To illustrate, let's break down a URI for retrieving a `user`:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{userid}
```

Breaking this into it's components we get:

- `GET` is the "HTTP verb" that defines the action we're taking. This follow the standard CRUD model:

  - `POST` = Create an entity or record
  - `GET` = Read an entity or record
  - `PATCH` = Update an entity or record
  - `DELETE` = Delete an entity or record
- `https://graph.microsoft.com` is the address for the Microsoft Graph itself .
- `/v1.0` is the version of the API you want to call (currently either `/v1.0` or `/beta`).
- `/users` tells Graph you're looking to access the `user` collection
- `/{userid}` tells Graph you're which specific user you're looking for within the `/users` collection

Since `/{userid}` is the final segment specified by the URL, it will return a JSON representation of that individual `User` record from Azure Active Directory.

You can find a good detailed explanation of how Microsoft Graph is organized in the article [Traverse Microsoft Graph](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/traverse_the_graph) in the [Microsoft Graph Documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs).

In your question you described two different calls:

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/{GUID}
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/{GUID}
```

The reason you're getting an error is that there is no namespace or method for the `{GUID}` you're sending it. It literally has no idea what you're asking for it to do. And since Microsoft Graph handles a slew of different services (SharePoint, Azure AD, Exchange, Planner, Teams, Groups, etc.) it couldn't even begin to guess at which service you're targeting.

Based on the additional comment you made, it sounds like you're trying to work with the [appRoleAssignment](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/resources/approleassignment). This endpoint is still in preview so it is only available in the `/beta` version. It also only supports `GET`, `UPDATE` and `DELETE` methods (`UPDATE` adds a user to the `appRoleAssignment`, `DELETE` removes a user from the `appRoleAssignment`).

You're call should therefore look something like this:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/{userId}/appRoleAssignments/{appRoleId}
```

You can find the full documentation for this call at [Update approleassignment](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/approleassignment_update).

Comment: still getting an error even with this format https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/{userId}/appRoleAssignments/{appRoleId}

:

Unsupported segment type. ODataQuery: users/{userid}/appRoleAssignments/{appRoleId}

Comment: By the way, since it's a beta version, is there any alternative to achieve what I want in c#?
Thanks for your response

Comment: You're missing a `/` between `users` and `{userId}`: `.../beta/users/{userId}/...`

Comment: No, it's only stackoverflow that is formatting it that way (i guess because '{' is not considered a valid url character)